# The use of a comma in context

Tags: punctuation

Tell me please it is correct to use a comma in the following sentence.

> Because he was tall, he was able to reach the ball.

Comment: What do you think? Have you checked any of the sites that advise people about the use of commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there would be a need to use comma after "tall" in formal writing. Because the rule is:

> You use comma to introduce a main clause after a subordinate one.